# Add multirow of data from data entry to database

Tags: google-sheets, data-entry, multirow

Currently, i'm working on a dashboard but i couldn't find any solution to solve a issue of my code where the problem is when i click the submit button, only the top row is recorded or save inside the Database. Below is an example (with image) of what i'm trying to achieve to this dashboard

Step 1: Submit Data from Data Entry
[Submission From Data Entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKDOl.png)

Step 2: Recorded in Database (Things i want to achieve)
[Recorded Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZcTm.png)

The issue i face:
[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7FtO.png)
only one data is recorded

Here is the code im currently working on right now

```
function Submit() {

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var form= ss.getSheetByName('Data Entry Form');
  var recordsSht=ss.getSheetByName('Billing Masterlist');

  var blankRow=datasheet.getLastRow()+1; //identify the next blank row

  recordsSht.getRange(blankRow,1).setValue(form.getRange("D8").getValue());
  recordsSht.getRange(blankRow,2).setValue(form.getRange("B8").getValue());
  recordsSht.getRange(blankRow,3).setValue(form.getRange("B12:B25").getValue());
  recordsSht.getRange(blankRow,4).setValue(form.getRange("C12:C25").getValue());
  recordsSht.getRange(blankRow,5).setValue(form.getRange("E12:E25").getValue());
  recordsSht.getRange(blankRow,6).setValue(form.getRange("F12:F25").getValue());
  recordsSht.getRange(blankRow,7).setValue(form.getRange("G12:F25").getValue());
  recordsSht.getRange(blankRow,8).setValue(form.getRange("H12:H25").getValue());
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your showing script, it seems that the destination sheet is different from the sheet obtained in the last row. I guess that this might be the reason for your current issue. In this case, please retrieve the last row from the destination sheet.
- When `appendRow` is used, `getLastRow()` is not required to be used.
- In your script, for example, `recordsSht.getRange(blankRow,3).setValue(form.getRange("B12:B25").getValue());` is used. In this case, the 1st cell of "B12:B25" is used. What is your expected result? If you want to use the values of "B12:B25", it is required to modify the script from `getValue` to `getValues`.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function Submit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var form = ss.getSheetByName('Data Entry Form');
  var recordsSht = ss.getSheetByName('Billing Masterlist');
  var convert = array => array[0].map((_, col) => array.map((row) => row[col] || "")).map(c => c.filter(String).join(", "));
  var values = [
    form.getRange("D8").getValue(),
    form.getRange("B8").getValue(),
    ...convert(form.getRange("B12:C25").getValues()), // or ...convert(form.getRange("B12:C25").getDisplayValues()), 
    ...convert(form.getRange("E12:H25").getValues()), // or ...convert(form.getRange("E12:H25").getDisplayValues()),
  ];
  recordsSht.appendRow(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values of "D8" and "B8" are appended into columns "A" and "B" of "Billing Masterlist" sheet. And, values of rows 12 to 25 of columns "B" to "C" are appended into columns "C" and "D" of "Billing Masterlist" sheet. And, values of rows 12 to 25 of columns "E" to "H" are appended into columns "E" to "H" of "Billing Masterlist" sheet.
- I'm not sure what you want to do at `recordsSht.getRange(blankRow,3).setValue(form.getRange("B12:B25").getValue())`. So, in this modification, the values of rows from 12 to 25 are converted to a string using `join`. If you want another result, please tell me.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))

### Added:

About your following reply,

> I want the result to be in multiple rows instead of a single row in the "Billing Masterlist" after submission from the data entry. For more clarification, can refer to Step 2 on what exactly I want it to be Here is the testing sheet for your reference

If my understanding of your following reply is correct, how about the following sample script?

```js
function Submit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var form = ss.getSheetByName('Data Entry Form');
  var recordsSht = ss.getSheetByName('Billing Masterlist');
  var [[b8, , d8]] = form.getRange("B8:D8").getValues();
  var b12h25 = form.getRange("B12:H25").getValues();
  var values = b12h25.reduce((ar, r) => {
    const [b, c, , ...efgh] = r;
    ar.push([d8, b8, b, c, ...efgh]);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (values.length == 0) return;
  recordsSht.getRange(recordsSht.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- I reflected your reply of `the issue now is it pulls everything including the empty row from the data entry form inside the billing master list instead of only a specific row`.

Comment: The result is still recorded in one row when I used the modification code, can refer to my attachment/image in step 2 above on what I want it to be.

Comment: I want the result to be in multiple rows instead of a single row in the "Billing Masterlist" after submission from the data entry.
For more clarification, can refer to Step 2 on what exactly I want it to be

Here is the testing sheet for your reference 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12plw-M6yA4ALyE_QxpSRRotCyH5pu_R186yGbRlobDw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Cyril_Leonel Thank you for replying and providing your sample Spreadsheet. When I saw your Spreadsheet, unfortunately, it seems that you don't use my proposed script. When I tested my proposed script, a new row was appended to "Billing Masterlist" sheet.

Comment: @Cyril_Leonel By guessing your expected result from your reply, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result and that was not useful, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Your new code works as I expected but the issue now is it pulls everything including the empty row from the data entry form inside the billing master list instead of only a specific row. 

Expectation:
example;
If only B12 to BL13 is keyed in, then only this value will be returned to the Billing Masterlist.

Comment: @Cyril_Leonel Thank you for replying. About `the issue now is it pulls everything including the empty row from the data entry form inside the billing master list instead of only a specific row`, I updated the bottom script. Please confirm it.

Comment: @Cyril_Leonel By the way, about `Expectation: example; If only B12 to BL13 is keyed in, then only this value will be returned to the Billing Masterlist.`, unfortunately, I cannot understand this. In your question, I cannot find this. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about your actual expected result? In order to understand it, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your actual expected result, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Cyril_Leonel In your showing script, it seems that you want to copy the values of "D8","B8","B12:B25","C12:C25","E12:E25","F12:F25","G12:F25","H12:H25". But, in your reply, it seems that you want to copy the values of "B12" to "BL13". I'm confused about your actual expected result. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. Can I ask you about the details of your actual expected result?

Comment: Your scripts work fine. Thank you!!, I just found the issue with my formula and your script is not the problem.  Sorry for the inconvenience. Thank you once again for your help and guidance.